# Why does the Onclick event not work on my ion col?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

My onclick event does not work on a ion-col, it keeps saying, whatever method i call "is not defined at html element.onclick"  my code snippet looks as follows

```html
<ion-row style="width:100%; height:6%; border: 1px solid #36B729; position:absolute; top:51.5%;">
            <!-- Wall Tab -->
            <ion-col id="WallTab" style="height:100%; border: 1px solid #36B729" align="center" onClick="TabManagement(this.id)">

              <font id="WallTab" style="color: #36B729; font-size: 70%;">Wall</font>

            </ion-col>
            <!-- Happy Customers Tab -->
            <ion-col id="HappyCustomersTab" style="height:100%; border: 1px solid #36B729" align="center" onClick="TabManagement(this.id)">

              <font id="HappyCustomersTab" style="color: white; font-size: 70%;">Happy Customers</font>

            </ion-col>
            <!-- Reports Tab -->
            <ion-col id="UnhappyCustomersTab" style="height:100%; border: 1px solid #36B729" align="center" onClick="GoBack();">

              <font id="UnhappyCustomersTab" style="color: white; font-size: 70%;">Unhappy Customers</font>

          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
```

My ts file looks as follows

public class profile{

TabManagement(){

code...

}
}

Comment: Please, add the js code of your component, at least a relevant snippet of it.

Comment: Also you could be using `(click)` instead of `onClick`

Comment: I added a relevant snippet of my ts code since this is in ionic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use just (click)="GoBack()"
And try use (click)="TabManagement(id)" without `this`